# BreezeJS. ContextProvider fall

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, breeze, provider

I'm trying solve this problem since morning.

When I'm doing save changes, contextProvider is losing information about connection string.

[image: screen 2]

So when I was trying to save changes a second time it failed!
[image: screen 3]

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Breeze.ContextProvider.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A connection string must be set on the
>   connection before you attempt this operation.

[image: screen 1]

What am I doing wrong? How to solve the problem?

P.S. Breeze v1.5.0 and EF 6.1.1

Comment: What does your ApiController look like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qrgP53NC

Comment: Are you missing the `[BreezeController]` attribute on your `BreezeController` class? I don't see it in the pastebin. Not saying that's the cause but I am wondering at its omission.

Comment: Thanks, it solved a few problems in client side, but the main problem remains

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The thing is the contextProvider was a static object.

Remove the static from the property and it will be fine